# What is a no tag line interpreted as?

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm currently wondering when to use clean text (not wrapped inside eg. `<p>` tags) in html documents.

i have a input fiels which i want some text before like:

```
<p>Age:</p> <input type="text" name="age">
```

But using the p tags as above will result in a linebreak between the two. However if I leave out the p tags this problem is no more.

My question is then wether it is OK to leave out the tags, and what in is interpreted as,

Thanks

Comment: `p{display:inline-block;}`, you should use `<span>Age:</span>` or `label`.

Comment: let's clarify - html doesn't make you use a particular tag and you can change the default behavior of tags to suite your needs or not use them at atll. that said: using the right tags helps with semantic meaning of the page (for not human readers),with applying css styles etc. the specific one to use before an input should be 'label' tag. the default to encompasse some text without a break is <span>

Comment: based on a book i recently read, it is best to wrap text in something rather than just leaving it an "orphan element" - one that is not wrapped by anything but the layout container like a `<div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there are many solutions as Webarto said you can style the p tag, or you can use span or label...People usually use label..I'll tell you why..

In good web designing principles one thing comes very important..

If you have some checkbox, or radiobutton, or textfield anything in your form then it should be selected just by clicking on the label assosiated with it..**User should not search for the 
radiobutton and then click, as it is very small, it should be triggered just by clicking the label**, user should not search for the textfield and then click inside it and then type..

```
<label for="id of input element"> attribute provides that function
```

Hence people prefer

```
 <label>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label) tag

Comment: While I've +1'd your answer (you are, after all, absolutely right), please consider linking to a reference with a better reputation than the W3Schools (which has precisely ***no*** connection to, or with, the W3, despite the implication of its name). May I suggest an alternative reference for the [label element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label), at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: Sure... the scope was to understand how to use the tag ;p then he can dig more about it, anyway cahnged as per your suggestion.

Comment: +1 from me too. please do not use w3schools at all. check this out http://w3fools.com

Comment: @naveen well seems hard... as in w3fool says they are usually first in google searches, that lazy people loves... and probably i'll continue to hit for instant reference purposes, keeping in mind that  I could find junk. But definitely not using anymore for reference especially for others ;) thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

The `p` element means in principle a paragraph, though HTML5 (and common practice) takes a liberal position on this: a “paragraph” is any block of text. But even under that interpretation, there is no reason to use `p` markup for a field label, as you do not want the label to appear in a block of its own. You might use `p` markup around the label and the corresponding input field, as in

```
<p><label for=age>Age:</label> <input type=text name=age id=age></p>
```

The reason is that you probably want to present such constructs as blocks, not consecutively all on one line. But then you need to remember that `p` markup implies default margins, corresponding to an empty line above and below. You can remove then using CSS, but a simpler and somewhat more logical approach is perhaps to use `div`, which indicates a block but with no default margins;

```
<div><label for=age>Age:</label> <input type=text name=age id=age></div>
```